# Visual Studio Apache Cordova issue

Tags: apache, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I installed Visual Studio 2015 Community with Apache Cordova and all projects now do not allow me to debug (devices or ripple) or complile(not errors, but does not create the apk).

I am attaching photos.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzgw4.png)

What can I do?

Thank you,

Comment: If I translate the error message, it looks like it's suggesting that you set the startup project (right-click the project in Solution Explorer and choose Set As Startup Project). If you try that, do you just keep seeing the same error message when you try to run?